# Ensure smooth Storyboard animation when UI Thread is blocked

Tags: c#, multithreading, animation, windows-phone-8, visual-glitch

In my WP8 application I have a `UserControl` with an active Storyboard animation that makes that `UserControl` to move in a desired direction. At some point during that animation I programmatically add second `UserControl` to the scene.

The problem is that second, dynamically added `UserControl` contains a lot of elements inside and takes substantial time to render. While it loads, the UI is being blocked for about 50 milliseconds on my phone and the glitch in first `UserControl`'s Storyboard animation is very noticable.

Question is what can I do about it? Should I somehow run animation in a different thread? If so then some general examples/links/manuals will help a lot because I'm not too versed in threads business. If that's not an option then I'd like to hear whatever can help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't advise threading on windows-phone; also you should avoid threading if you have data that needs to be shared between threads.  It can be done but it's not easy.

If possible I would pre-load your user controls (or group of controls) and then show/hide them as they are needed. That should prevent the glitch you are seeing.  If you need help with how to preload please post some example of how you are dynamically loading your controls and we may be able to assist you.

If you do need to do multi-threading I would advise using a background worker more details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: +1. Preloading seems the only thing to do. The problem is that all rendering and prepation IS single threaded (has to happenin the UI thread). "contains lots of elemtns and takes substantial time to render" totally rules out a second thread per UI STA thread model.

Comment: I think preloading is not possible or at least very hard to do in my situation because dynamic UserControls depend on external data that varies every time and is passed to them on creation.

Comment: I've read your link and I see how these workers can be used for some intensive number crunching for example but how can i use them for my Storyboard animation?
@TomTom Do I get it right that workers/threads can't help me here because all the UI must be done in one thread?

Comment: I could, however, wait until the animation is ended and then add new UserControl to the scene because the animation is fast. That will lower interface speed perception for users but at least will have no glitches. If nothing else, I guess I'll do it this way.

Comment: @Anton as per WPF, Winforms and general UI spec, all interaction with UI elements must happen on the thread that created them. Simple like that. The UI is inherently single threaded. So, you ca not use another thread to create a new object, then attach it to the UI - threads would mix.

Comment: @Anton without knowing more about what you dynamic controls contain I can't be much more help.  You should be able to pre-create your controls (have all the graphics and stuff ready) and then call a method to update just the parts that need to be changed; that could save a bit of processing time.

Comment: Also, what I have done in some of my apps, is create variables that store calculated values and then only run the calculation process if something that it uses has been updated. I use DateTime fields to store the time they were last updated, and do comparisons.

Comment: @AnthonyNichols, I've decided to add new control right after animation ends and thankfully look and feel of that turned out to be pretty nice. Thanks for the help anyway.